# PostgreSQL Permission to delete records but not table/column

Tags: postgresql, privileges

Im trying to give access to postgres database

the role can perform to delete a row/record in a table but cannot delete the table.

I've tried to revoke delete access from tables. but it prevent to delete row/record as well.

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Only the owner of a table (or a superuser) can drop (or alter) the table. So there is nothing you need to do

Comment: But I want role have access to delete row/records. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: `grant select, delete on the_table to the_role`

Comment: but grant delete means role can delete tables right. ?

so there's no other way to do it.

if delete is granted. means role can delete records/column/table.

Comment: No, `delete` means delete _rows_. Tables are dropped, not deleted